# String conversion of special character

Tags: string, spring, logstash

JSON parsing exception is thrown from logstash whenever ® is encountered.
I need to convert ® into its equivalent HTML encoded value and then push it into ES through logstash.
I got few articles where its mentioned how to convert the HTML codes into equivalent symbols but am looking for the reverse case.

If I pass "®" then it should return me `&#174;` but if `&#174;` is passed then it should not format it and still it should return `&#174;`

Update:

Below is the script i am using to push data into ES

```
input{    file    {        path => ["C:/input.json"]
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
}}filter{
mutate
{
    replace => [ "message", "%{message}" ]
    gsub => [ 'message','\n','']
}
json { source => message }
mutate{
    remove_field => ["message"]
}}output {
   elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "index"
            document_type => "type"
            document_id => "%{id}"
   }
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
```

}

How can i solve this issue

Comment: If you are using the json codec on an input, perhaps you could use the charset option to specify a charset supporting ®